# Circles passing at most through one point with integer coordinates

Tags: proof-verification, analytic-geometry, integers

I am having fun with some problems and am wondering if my solution to the following one is correct and well written.

> Prove that a circle centered at the point $C=\left(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}\right)$ in the Cartesian plane passes at most through one point with integer coordinates.

I go by contradiction: assume there exists a circle centered at $C$ passing through two points $(x_1,y_1)\neq(x_2,y_2)$, with $x_i,y_i \in \mathbb{Z}, i = 1,2$. Let $R > 0$ be the radius of such a circle. Then 
\begin{align}
\left(x_1-\sqrt{2}\right)^2+\left(y_1-\sqrt{3}\right)^2&=R^2,\\
\left(x_2-\sqrt{2} \right)^2+\left(y_2-\sqrt{3} \right)^2&=R^2.
\end{align}
Subtracting the two equations and simplifying I get 
$$\left(x_1-x_2\right)\left(x_1+x_2-2\sqrt{2}\right)+\left(y_1-y_2\right)\left(y_1+y_2-2\sqrt{3} \right)=0.$$
Define $m:=x_1-x_2, n:=x_1+x_2, r:=y_1-y_2, s:=y_1+y_2$. By assumption $m,n,r,s$ are integers, and I can rewrite the equation above as
$$mn-2\sqrt{2}m+rs-2\sqrt{3}r=0$$
which reduces to saying that 
$$\sqrt{2}m'+\sqrt{3}r' \in \mathbb{Z}$$
for $m'=2m, r'=2r$. If I assume one between $m'$ and $r'$ is not zero, then squaring I would get that $\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}, \sqrt{6}$ are rational, which is false. So $m'=r'=0$, which means $m=r=0$, so 
$x_1=x_2,y_1=y_2$, contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

If there were two points with rational coordinates the center’s irrational coordinates $c_1$, $c_2$ and $1$ are $\mathbb Q$-linearly dependent.

Consider the normal of the midpoint $(m_1,m_2)$ of these points.

The normal’s slope $q$ and the coordinates of the midpoint are rational. Now the center of the circle lies on the normal, hence we have 
$$q=\frac{m_2-c_2}{m_1-c_1}\Rightarrow qc_1-c_2\in\mathbb Q.$$

PS: If there are three points with rational coordinates, the center must have rational coordinates, too.

Comment: I do not see how the coordinates of the centre are linearly dependent over $\mathbb{Q}$. Can you give more details?

Comment: See my edit, please.

Comment: What if $m_1 = c_1$? You should fix this. I see your point anyway, and thanks for this alternative solution. However, my question was if my solution looks correct and is well written.

Comment: Fixed, thank you.